# Not able to use Electron's webview on Windows

Tags: electron

I have a [simple react app](https://github.com/deepak/react-todo). It uses:

- react
- webpack
- redux
- css-modules

Was looking for an easy way to wrap a React app into Electron.
Am trying out `webview`

Have a [simple electron app](https://github.com/deepak/electron-webview-todo)

It works on OSX but not on Windows 10, 
Please help.

It opens up the Electron app but nothing is visible in the `webview`
I have opened devtools in both the Electron renderer process and the webview,
but i do not see any error messages

I have tried:

1. electro-forge
2. electron and electron-packager

steps to run the app

install the global dependencies:

1. install node LTS ie. v6.9.2
2. install `electron-forge` with "npm install -g electron-forge"

run the React app:

1. git clone https://github.com/deepak/react-todo
2. cd react-todo
3. npm install
4. npm start
5. open "http://localhost:3000/todo" and "http://localhost:3000/" on the browser and checks that it works

run the Electron app:

1. git clone https://github.com/deepak/electron-webview-todo
2. cd electron-webview-todo
3. npm install
4. npm start (works on OSX but not windows 10)
5. we are using `electron-forge` here
6. try the same with plain Electron at the [use-electron-packager-and-not-electron-forge](https://github.com/deepak/electron-webview-todo/tree/use-electron-packager-and-not-electron-forge) branch

Answer (score 0):

I was loading "http://0.0.0.0:3000"
It works when i load "http://localhost:3000/" instead